# SSMS Linked Server from PostgreSQL query fails when adding WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, ssms, linked-server

I have Linked server from PostgreSQL 12 to my SSMS and trying to join two PostgreSQL tables and insert the result to my table with the stored procedure.
The problem I have is when adding a WHERE clause it starts displaying NULLs in the second table and I know there are values in there. Please see the examples below:

First query:

```
SELECT
    a.hardware_id AS [HardwareID], 
    a.created_at AS CreatedAt,
    ISNULL(b.serial, NULL) AS [DiskSerial],
    ISNULL(b.model, NULL) AS [DiskModel],
    ISNULL(b.vendor, NULL) AS [DiskMake],
    ISNULL(b.type_display, NULL) AS [DiskType],
    ISNULL(b.transport, NULL) AS [DiskTransport],
    ISNULL(b.status_display, NULL) AS [DiskStatus],
    ISNULL(b.capacity_display, NULL) AS [DiskCapacity],
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DATETIME, b.erase_finish_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'), NULL) AS [DiskEraseFinishTime],
    ISNULL(b.device_id, NULL) AS [DiskEraseID],
    ISNULL(b.erase_algorithm_display, NULL) AS [DiskEraseMethod],
    ISNULL(b.erase_level, NULL) AS [DiskEraseLevel],
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DATETIME, b.erase_start_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'), NULL) AS [DiskEraseStartTime],
    ISNULL(b.erase_result_display, NULL) AS [DiskEraseResult]
FROM [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[public].[hardware] AS a
LEFT JOIN [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[public].[disk_device] AS b 
    ON a.hardware_id = b.hardware_id
```

Running this query returns 3393 rows:
[image: Result 3393 rows]

Now when I add a WHERE clause to the query the second table is displayed as NULLs apart from the first record

Second query added WHERE:

```
SELECT
    a.hardware_id AS [HardwareID], 
    a.created_at AS CreatedAt,
    ISNULL(b.serial, NULL) AS [DiskSerial],
    ISNULL(b.model, NULL) AS [DiskModel],
    ISNULL(b.vendor, NULL) AS [DiskMake],
    ISNULL(b.type_display, NULL) AS [DiskType],
    ISNULL(b.transport, NULL) AS [DiskTransport],
    ISNULL(b.status_display, NULL) AS [DiskStatus],
    ISNULL(b.capacity_display, NULL) AS [DiskCapacity],
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DATETIME, b.erase_finish_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'), NULL) AS [DiskEraseFinishTime],
    ISNULL(b.device_id, NULL) AS [DiskEraseID],
    ISNULL(b.erase_algorithm_display, NULL) AS [DiskEraseMethod],
    ISNULL(b.erase_level, NULL) AS [DiskEraseLevel],
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DATETIME, b.erase_start_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'), NULL) AS [DiskEraseStartTime],
    ISNULL(b.erase_result_display, NULL) AS [DiskEraseResult]
FROM [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[public].[hardware] AS a
LEFT JOIN [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[public].[disk_device] AS b 
    ON a.hardware_id = b.hardware_id WHERE a.created_at >= '2023-10-10'
```

Running this query returns filtered data of 1551 rows but without values from the second table, **I want to get this number of rows (filtered by a.created_at) with the data populated for the rest of the columns**:
[image]

I tried changing WHERE clause to AND and this does not filter results by a.created_at

Third query:

```
SELECT
    a.hardware_id AS [HardwareID], 
    a.created_at AS CreatedAt,
    ISNULL(b.serial, NULL) AS [DiskSerial],
    ISNULL(b.model, NULL) AS [DiskModel],
    ISNULL(b.vendor, NULL) AS [DiskMake],
    ISNULL(b.type_display, NULL) AS [DiskType],
    ISNULL(b.transport, NULL) AS [DiskTransport],
    ISNULL(b.status_display, NULL) AS [DiskStatus],
    ISNULL(b.capacity_display, NULL) AS [DiskCapacity],
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DATETIME, b.erase_finish_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'), NULL) AS [DiskEraseFinishTime],
    ISNULL(b.device_id, NULL) AS [DiskEraseID],
    ISNULL(b.erase_algorithm_display, NULL) AS [DiskEraseMethod],
    ISNULL(b.erase_level, NULL) AS [DiskEraseLevel],
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DATETIME, b.erase_start_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'), NULL) AS [DiskEraseStartTime],
    ISNULL(b.erase_result_display, NULL) AS [DiskEraseResult]
FROM [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[public].[hardware] AS a
LEFT JOIN [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[public].[disk_device] AS b 
    ON a.hardware_id = b.hardware_id AND a.created_at >= '2023-10-10'
```

Running this query returns 3270 rows for some reason and filtering does not work as well:
[image]

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like applicaton; you don't have a linked server in SSMS you have a linked server in your database engine. Presumably that's SQL Server? That you are using SSMS to *connect* to your instance is very likely completely irrelevant.

Comment: Your `AND a.created_at >= '2023-10-10'` is in the **`ON`** for the `LEFT JOIN` to `disk_device`; you should expect rows that have a value less than `2023-10-10` as those rows will have no related rows in the table "b" is for "disk_device" (what `b`..?).

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: `ISNULL(b.serial, NULL)`? Why? Why return `NULL` if the value of `b.serial` is `NULL`? It's *already* `NULL`. It's like having `CASE MyColumn WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE MyColumn END`; it might as well be `MyColumn`.

Comment: That's Correct @ThomA RE_1: Its SQL Server,

Comment: @ThomA RE_2: I wanted to get results where created_at is higher than '2023-10-10' and table b does not have created_at field

Comment: @ThomA RE_3: Sorry will try to improve my sql habbits

Comment: So what you want is `WHERE a.created_at >= '2023-10-10'`. That you are getting `NULL`s for the columns from the table "`b`" means that there are no related rows.

Comment: @ThomA RE_4:  Correct this is not necessary but I didn't know why it was returning null so I added that there thinking it would help, this check can be removed. Saying that apart from commenting about my code four times, you didn't really help, but thanks for your tips

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255995/discussion-between-pawel-g-and-thom-a).

Comment: So your question isn't about your code, and why it's not returning the results you want? Then I suggest taking the time to [edit] your question to explain what is it you are *actually* asking.

Comment: Thanks @ThomA , my main concern is highlighted in bold

Comment: So then, presumably, the problem is your `ON` clause; we can't run your queries we as we don't have access to your instance and you haven't supplied sample data. YOu'll need to figure out *why* the no related rows are found in your other table (or provide **consumable** sample data). If you are sure that the clause is correct, then I already explain the reason in my prior [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77515925/ssms-linked-server-from-postgresql-query-fails-when-adding-where-clause?noredirect=1#comment136656563_77515925) (you appear to have disregarded).